How to create a stipple or halftone effect on objects with volume shaders?
I'm trying to create a stipple or halftone effect in Blender on images composed by objects that use volume shaders like these (mostly principled volume shader and playing with emission and density).

Reference stipple, halftone:


I'm looking for guidance on how to achieve this effect.
I've considered a few approaches:

Mapping the textures created with volumetrics to surfaces, and then using the same shaders/geom nodes that are typically used for surfaces.
Applying the effect in the compositing stage.

What would be the best approach and how I can achieve it?
Thank you!
